# Python: Sort subsection of columns

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

Suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
Label1  2016-03-31  2016-05-31  2016-04-30
0   A   A1              1            6
1   B   B1              3            4
2   C   C2              5            7
3   D   D1              7            2
4   E   E4              9            4
5   F   F1              11           6
```

Which can be computed as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
A = pd.DataFrame([['A','A1',1, 6], ['B','B1' ,3,4], ['C', 'C2', 5,7], ['D','D1',7,2], ['E','E4',9,4], ['F','F1',11,6]], columns=['Label1',pd.to_datetime('2016-03-31') , pd.to_datetime('2016-05-31'),pd.to_datetime('2016-04-30')])
```

I was wondering whether it's possible to sort the dataframe based on the dates labels of the last three columns. I would want the end result to look as

```
Label1  2016-03-31  2016-04-30 2016-05-31   
0   A   A1              6            1
1   B   B1              4            3
2   C   C2              7            5
3   D   D1              2            7
4   E   E4              4            9
5   F   F1              6            11
```

Comment: `u = A.set_index('Label1'); u.reindex(u.columns.sort_values(), axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
new_cols = list(df.columns[:-3]) + list(df.columns[-3:].sort_values())

df[new_cols]
```

Output:

```
  Label1 2016-03-31  2016-04-30  2016-05-31
0      A         A1           6           1
1      B         B1           4           3
2      C         C2           7           5
3      D         D1           2           7
4      E         E4           4           9
5      F         F1           6          11
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
s=pd.to_datetime(A.columns,errors='coerce').dropna()
A[A.columns.difference(s,sort=False).union(sorted(s),sort=False)]
```

---

```
  Label1 2016-03-31 00:00:00  2016-04-30 00:00:00  2016-05-31 00:00:00
0      A                  A1                    6                    1
1      B                  B1                    4                    3
2      C                  C2                    7                    5
3      D                  D1                    2                    7
4      E                  E4                    4                    9
5      F                  F1                    6                   11
```

Comment: This isn't what he is trying to do.  Check his output.

Comment: @user3483203 Fixed now, i think i missed the `sorted()` in the union.